# Equation involving factorials

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Find all integers a,b,c satisfying

$$a!b! = a! + b! + c!$$

Without loss of generality, we can write $b$ as $a-k$ (k is a positive integer), so we get

$$c! = a!(a-k)! - (a! + (a-k)!)$$

and so $c!$ must be divisible by $(a-k)!$, it follows that $c! = (a-k+r)!$ (where $r$ is a positive integer). I don't know what to do next. Not sure if what I have done is even on the right track, seems like all I have done is replaced $b,c$ by $k,r$

Comment: I don't see why $c!=(a-k+r)!$ follows from $(a-k)!$ divides $c!$.  Can you expand on that step?

Comment: It is reasonable to state that $a \ge b$, but you have claimed $a \gt b$, (because you say $k$ is positive) which needs justification.  The equation seems unlikely to have solutions because the factorials are so rare.

Comment: @ Ross Millikan : I meant to say k is non-negative. I know of one solution, 3!3! = 3! + 3! + 4! .

Comment: @ Gregory Grant : The right hand side of the equation is a!(a-k)! - (a! + (a-k)!) , this is divisible by (a-k)!.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WOLOG let $a \ge b$.  We can't have $b=1$ as the equation becomes $0=1+c!$, nor $b=2$ as the equation becomes $a!=2+c!$
$b \ge 3, b! \ge 6,$ and $c \gt a$
Then if $b \lt a$ we can divide by $a!$ and get $b!=1+\frac {b!}{a!} + \frac {c!}{a!}$ which fails because $\frac {b!}{a!}$ is not an integer.
So $a=b$ and the equation becomes $(a!)^2=2(a!)+c!$ or $a!=2+\frac {c!}{a!}$
The left side is a multiple of $3$, so $c$ cannot be greater than $a+2$.
We can solve $a!=2+(a+1)$ for $a=3$, giving $3!3!=3!+3!+4!$, but $a$ cannot be greater as the factorial grows too fast.
There are no solutions to $a!=2+(a+1)(a+2)=a^2+3a+4$ as the left side is too small at $a=4$ and too big at $a=5$

The only solution is $3!3!=3!+3!+4!$

Comment: Can you please explain to me why c > a in the third line?

Comment: Because $a!b! \ge 6a!,$ and $a! + b! + c! \le c!+2a!,$ so $c! \ge  4a!$